# CIC Idle reset pending

Tags: asterisk, ivr, ss7

Trying to create ss7 signalling link but m getting following `ss7 linestat`

. I have tried everything but got failed to resolve below issues.

```
l4isup.c: T22 timeout (No "circuit group reset acknowledge" from peer)

CIC  20 Idle Reset pending
```

Anyone has idea about this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have sort out the above issue. This issue was at telco end. `CIC` was not resetting from telco end, they have configured S`S7 Signalling link` at their end, after that I was able to see `CIC Idle`. Now there is no any such error or warning at `Asterisk` Console. Also `SS7 linestat` is now idle.